# Return Out Param value to VBScript

Tags: oracle, plsql, vbscript

Below is an example of **trying** to return the value of a PL/SQL output parameter to VBScript.

My actual requirement is far more complicated, but to simplify and for me to be able to learn, I am just trying to return the value of a hello world Proc.

See below examples.

On my local laptop DB I have created

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE procOneOUTParameter(outParam1 OUT VARCHAR2)
IS
BEGIN
    outParam1 := 'Hello World OUT parameter';
END;
/
```

VBScript I am trying - but am getting a "wrong type" error:

```vb
Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
cn.Open "Driver={Oracle in XE};Dbq=localhost:1521/xe;User Id=xxx;Password=xxx;"
Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
Set cmd.ActiveConnection = cn
cmd.CommandType = 4
cmd.CommandText = "procOneOUTParameter"
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("outParam1", adVarChar, adParamOutput, , outParam1)
cmd.Execute
```

Comment: So does your code work? If not Error number, error message, error source. Also line number.

Comment: Error at line 7 "arguments are of the wrong type, are out of acceptable range, or are in conflict with another"

Comment: VBScript doesn't do type libraries `constants`. All your constants need to be defined in the script. IE `const adVarChar=<whatever>`. VBScript late binds so has no information about your call till you make it, unlike early binding in VBA via the References dialog..

Comment: You cannot use named constants, this list should help you: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bradchen/2016/08/30/vbscript-common-constants/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Const adVarChar = 200
Const adParamOutput= 2
Const adCmdStoredProc= 4

Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
cn.Open "Driver={Oracle in XE};Dbq=localhost:1521/xe;User Id=XXX;Password=XXX;"
Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
Set cmd.ActiveConnection = cn
cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
cmd.CommandText = "procOneOUTParameter"
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@outParam1",adVarChar,adParamOutput,200)
cmd.Execute
getParam = cmd.Parameters("@outParam1").Value
WScript.Echo getParam
```